# Prove, that $3^n+3$ can't be a square

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, divisibility, integers

How can I prove, that $3^n+3$ can't be a square over the positive integers? The only hint/requirement I have is that I need to solve it using mathematical induction. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the highest power of $3$ dividing $3^n + 3$?

Comment: Do you know how to do induction? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: @Bram I'm okay with induction, I simply can't encapsulate the nth elementh into the n+1th so that it actually is useful to me

Comment: @Bálint Yeah, I must say I don't really see how induction really helps here either ...

Comment: $3^n + 3$ **is** a square when $n = 0$.

Comment: @Rob Please read the question

Comment: I did read the question: "over the positive integers" is fairly meaningless in this context. If you'd written "where $n$ is a positive integer", that would have been fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint** $3|3^n+3$.

If $3$ divides a perfect square, then $9$ divides it too.

Answer (score 3):

Because $3^n+3=3(3^{n-1}+1)$ is divided by $3$ and it's not divided by $9$.

Answer (score 1):

For positive integers:

$$3^n+3=3(3^{n-1}+1)$$

But $\;3^n+1\;$ is *never* divisible by three , so the above has only one prime divisor $\;3\;$ , and this means that can't be a square.